# Cakephp - joining tables, NOT in

Tags: cakephp

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to make a Query but don't get it how to do the Query in cake-style. I want to do a query that Selects all respondents thats not in a particular transformational. Examples at the bottom. Cakephp v 2.4.5

I have to three tables/models:

Resondents: id, name

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Transformational' => array(
        'className' => 'Transformational',
        'joinTable' => 'transformationals_respondents',
        'foreignKey' => 'respondent_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'transformational_id',
        'unique' => true
    )
);
```

Transformationals: id, name

```
   public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Respondent' => array(
            'className' => 'Respondent',
        'joinTable' => 'transformationals_respondents',
        'foreignKey' => 'transformational_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'respondent_id',
        'unique' => true
        ),
};
```

TransformationasRespondent: id, transformational_id, respondent_id
    This is a join table

Example tables:
respondent: id, name
1, Abc
2, Def
3, Ghi
4, Jkl

transformationals: id, name
1, Macrosoft
2, Eddy
3, Wag

transformationals_respondents: id, respondent_id, transformational_id
1, 1, 7
2, 2, 7

THen I need Query to SELECT respondents thats NOT in transformationals_respondents and has transformational_id 7. Ie. respondent Ghi and Jkl

I would really appreciate a hand here.

Comment: Either ask this as a MySQL question, or include the actual query you're hoping to build with Cake.  By listing both in the same question, it comes off as "can you build this for me".

Comment: This is way off-topic. I cant see the reason to ask this in an MySql section, its a Cake question. Making this query in MySql is not a problemt. Does anyone know about another forum to ask this kind a questions, this forum has gotn to much effort consuming. I cant see the problem about can you bild this to me. For a person used to cake this would be a fairly simples question. I got into this same issue in another thread here on the forum an explained the topic quit extensive. No respons at all. Why use a big effort in explaining the problem for at person who does not understand how to answer?

Comment: You don't get it.  If it's not a problem, then supply the MySQL query you'd like to convert, and I'm glad to help - but you should not ask us to both WRITE the query FOR you AND then convert it into CakePHP.  Understand?

Answer (score 0):

Create one function in Respondent model as

```
function getSomeSome(){

$options = array(
        'conditions' => array('Transformational.id'=>7,'TransformationasRespondent.id IS NULL'),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'TransformationasRespondent',  
                'table' => 'transformationals_respondents',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'TransformationasRespondent.respondent_id = Respondent.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'alias' => 'Transformational',  
                'table' => 'transformationals',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'TransformationasRespondent.transformational_id = Transformational.id',
                ),
            ),

        )
    );
  $returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
  # returnData contains all the records having transformational_id equals to 7 and
  # does nt have any recors in TransformationasRespondent table
}
```